# What are these errors of ignoring file?

Tags: apt

`N: Ignoring file 'google-chrome.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'steam.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'google-chrome.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'steam.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension`

Answer (score 2):

Files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` are taken into account only if they have a `.list` extension. Anything else is ignored, with the message you're seeing.

As to why you have these files disabled, I don't know if anyone here will have the answer...